# Evil package/alternative for motion through CamelCase words?

Tags: evil

Most programming languages use CamelCase 
("anIdentifier") naming conventions 
for identifiers. With Evil, you could navigate inside those identifiers using Evil 
built-in motions is the `[count]f{char}` motion, i.e. f`{uppercase-char}` or f_, 
respectively. But I would like to have this easier. I noticed there are many plugins available for Vim, which enables you to move camelCase-wise.

These packages defines motions ,w ,b and ,e (similar to w b e), which do 
not move word-wise (forward/backward), but Camel-wise; i.e. to word boundaries 
and uppercase letters. Outside of "words" (e.g. in non-keyword 
characters like // or ;), the new motions move just like the regular motions.

For example, with the CamelCase plugin the cursor (`[]`) is on the following sentence:

```
[]AnotherExampleOfFoobar
```

When I type <kbd>dw</kbd>, it will change to the following:

```
[]ExampleOfFoobar.
```

When I googled around for an alternative package for Evil, I found no alternative package for CamelCase motion. It deletes the whole `AnotherExampleOfFoobar`, instead deleting `Another`.

So I guess there is a missing feature, that I need to implement it in some way. So have anyone any suggestion to start with it?

Comment: You're probably looking for [`subword-mode`](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/08/27/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-superword-mode/).

Comment: https://github.com/tarao/evil-plugins/blob/master/evil-little-word.el

Comment: @wasamasa  Thanks wasama, after trying out `evil-little-word` package, it seems it adds new commands next to the existing Evil commands. It adds a layer of complexitiy to Evil, which I don't want. The CamelCase plugin in Vim works with the default Vim commands. It stops on subwords, I would prefer that, instead adding new commands from `evil-little-word` next to the default Evil commands. Any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps this can work, but we just remap things like `w` to `evil-forward-little-word-end` and `iw` to `evil-inner-little-word`? I'm not sure about how to rebind evil keybindings, but it seems like a promising approach...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [evil-little-word](https://github.com/tarao/evil-plugins/blob/master/evil-little-word.el) library as suggested by @wasamasa above, you can rebind your standard vim bindings to the evil-little-word versions.

For example, once you load that library in your path, put this in your init file:

```
(require 'evil-little-word)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "w") 'evil-forward-little-word-begin)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "b") 'evil-backward-little-word-begin)
(define-key evil-operator-state-map (kbd "w") 'evil-forward-little-word-begin)
(define-key evil-operator-state-map (kbd "b") 'evil-backward-little-word-begin)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "w") 'evil-forward-little-word-begin)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "b") 'evil-backward-little-word-begin)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "i w") 'evil-inner-little-word)
```

I think that covers the bindings, but let me know if I am missing something!

To figure this out, I asked another question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20151/how-to-rebind-evil-key-mappings?noredirect=1#20151) about the details of re-binding evil-mode keys.

Comment: Whoa, that worked surprisingly well. Sorry for the belated response. But I couldn't get it working earlier. Later I thought I could give a try again, and it works now! Thanks for that, it's appreciated!

Comment: Haha, your welcome! As with most things in life (and emacs), it was a concerted effort. Thanks wasamasa for finding the library, and @Dan for helping with the configuration. Enjoy :D

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks. It's nice to know that this still lets you replace the whole word with `cio`!