# How to rebind evil key mappings for delete and friends?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, keymap

I am looking to rebind some evil mode keys used in navigation and text selection. For example, I am able to successfully map the following evil-mode keys to the following functions:

```el
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "w") 'evil-forward-little-word-begin)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "b") 'evil-backward-little-word-begin)
```

But I don't know how to bind key combinations, like using `dw` to delete only to the next little word. For example, I type `d C-h k w` to describe the `w` key after I have typed `d`, and it is mapped to `evil-forward-word-begin`, and not to `evil-forward-little-word-begin`. Apparently, my key mapping above does not work for this scenario.

Is there a way to remap this keybinding, or am I being unreasonable in my attempt to remap the evil-little-word library?

Note that this question is a tangent to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14439/evil-package-alternative-for-motion-through-camelcase-words) and I am trying to remap the [evil-little-word](https://github.com/tarao/evil-plugins/blob/master/evil-little-word.el) library to the regular evil-mode keybindings.

Comment: Sadly, StackExchange does not support Github Flavored Markdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions such as `evil-delete` (<kbd>d</kbd>) and `evil-change` (<kbd>c</kbd>) are *operators*, so you need to modify the `evil-operator-state-map`.  If you want these modifications to show up in visual state as well, also modify `evil-visual-state-map`.

Have a look at [Evil's bitbucket page](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/wiki/Home) for more details.  It includes an old [manual](https://bytebucket.org/lyro/evil/raw/default/doc/evil.pdf), but it will still give you enough of the core background to get started.